# Understand to paragraphs in Chicones book concerning tangent vector fields

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality

I apologize in advance for the length of this question....

Now, consider the sphere $$ S:=\{ (x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now in Chicone's book "Ordinary differential equations" on pp. 53 proving that $S$ is an invariant manifold of some ODE boils down to proving that *$S$ is everywhere tangent to the vector field $$ (x,y,z)\mapsto (x^2-Ax,y^2-Ay,z^2-Az),$$where $A:=x^3+y^3+z^3$*.

Keep in mind that at this point only the concept of manifold but **not** the concept of tangent space is introduced. His argument why the sentence written in italic holds is the following:

[image]

My questions are:

1) Can someone please give me reference (or recall for me) this definition of tangency of vectors to spheres from euclidean geometry ? (Later on the concept of tangent space at a manifold is introduced, but I don't want to make use of later concepts in his book to understand earlier ones; as he phrased it, there should be somewhere in basic euclidean geometry a definition of this type of tangency).

2) I don't understand his argument at all, because in my basic geometry class things like normal lines weren't introduced - only normal vectors, which I know how to calculate. Also how can I derive how the *outer normal unit field* looks like ?

3) A minor question (if someone has the time - if not ignore this one): What does generally mean that a vector field is tangent to a manifold, how can I visualize this ? (A reference to a (well discussed) definition would suffice here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding (1): Tangency at spheres.
We work in $\mathbb R^n$ with Euclidean scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ in an orthonormal basis. Then, we have the sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin: $S_r = \{x\in \mathbb R^n|\langle x,x\rangle = r^2\}.$ Pick a point $y$ in $S_r$ and a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ and consider the line $z = y+\lambda v$ with parameter $\lambda \in \mathbb R.$ This line is tangent to $S_r$ iff it intersects $S_r$ only in $y.$ In order to calculate the intersections of $z$ and $S_r,$ we solve
$$
\langle y+\lambda v,y+\lambda v\rangle = r^2
$$
for $\lambda.$ We calculate
$$
r^2 = \langle y+\lambda v,y+\lambda v\rangle = \langle y,y\rangle + 2\lambda\langle y,v\rangle + \lambda^2\langle v,v\rangle,
$$
which, by using $\langle y,y\rangle = r^2,$ is equivalent to
$$
0 = 2\lambda\langle y,v\rangle + \lambda^2\langle v,v\rangle.
$$
In order for $z$ to intersect $S_r$ only in $y,$ this equation must have the unique solution $\lambda = 0.$ This is the case iff $\langle y,v\rangle = 0.$ Also note that $\langle v,v\rangle \neq 0$ since $v\neq 0.$ So we have shown that the vector $v$ is tangent to $S_r$ in the point $y \in S_r$ iff $\langle y,v\rangle = 0.$ If you think about all this for a very short time, you will realize that it makes sense to drop the requirement $v\neq 0.$

Regarding (2): Vector field and unit sphere. We consider the unit sphere $S_1 \subseteq \mathbb R^3$ and the vector field $V(x,y,z) = (x^2-Ax,y^2-Ay,z^2-Az)$ for $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3.$ with $A = x^3+y^3+z^3.$ We want that for any $(x,y,z) \in S_1,$ $V(x,y,z)$ is tangent to $S_1$ in the point $(x,y,z).$ According to (1), we just have to calculate
$$
\begin{align}
\langle (x,y,z),V(x,y,z) \rangle & = x^3-Ax^2+y^3-Ay^2+z^3-Az^2 \\
& = A-A(x^2+y^2+z^2) \\
& = A - A\cdot 1 \\
& = 0,
\end{align}
$$
as desired. Note that we have used $(x,y,z) \in S_1.$

Regarding (3): Manifolds and tangent vectors. Say, you have a smooth surface element M (or some higher-dimensional analogue) embedded in some $\mathbb R^n.$ Think of a sphere or a torus. Consider a smooth curve $c: I\rightarrow M, t \mapsto c(t)$ where $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ is some open interval. Then we can differentiate $c$ with respect to $t$ as in multivariate calculus and get a vector $c'(t)$ at the point $c(t) \in M.$ Then $c'(t)$ is a tangent vector at $M$ in $c(t).$ In fact, you can get all tangent vectors in this way. Just to convince you, let's apply this construction to the unit sphere. So, suppose that $c$ runs entirely in the unit sphere, i.e. $\langle c(t),c(t)\rangle \equiv 1$ is constant. By differenting, we get
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt}1 = \frac{d}{dt}\langle c(t),c(t)\rangle = 2\langle c'(t),c(t)\rangle,
$$
which is exactly our condition from (1) for tangent vectors at the unit sphere. Nice, isn't it? :-) In fact, this calculation is one of the slick tricks from differential geometry. :-) :-) You can find all this in much more detail in any good book on that subject.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! 1) and 2) are now  clear to me (and Chicones talk about "base point" and "principal part" of a vector now seems to me to be nonsense, since in $\mathbb{R}^n$ all vectors have base point $0$ - and what a principal part would be, I don't know). Concerning 3) the only questions I have is: When you said "Then $c′(t)$ is a tangent vector at $M$ in $c(t)$", you must have had already a general definition of tangency in mind, [...]

Comment: [...] which this particular case fulfills, right ? Since for some general surface $M$ we don't have a simple scalar product of it, which permits us to make a simple definition of tangency. And could you tell me more about this slick trick ? For me this feels like algebraic wizardry right now...

Comment: @arila Regarding "base point" and "principal part" of a tangent vector. I'm not familiar with thes particular designations, but I think the underlying concepts are quite important. Consider, for example, the unit sphere $S_1 \subseteq \mathbb R^3.$ Pick an $x\in S_1$ and a $v\in\mathbb R^3$ which is tangent at $S_1$ in $x$ (i.e. $\langle x,v\rangle = 0$). Now, if you pick a $y \in S_1\setminus\{x\},$ then it's very likely that $v$ is _not_ tangent to $S_1$ in $y$ (because the condition $\langle y,v\rangle = 0$ is not necessarily true).

Comment: @arila [continued] So, if we think about it, the complete description of the tangent vector $v$ at $S_1$ in $x$ consists of the pair $(x,v),$ where $x$ is the "base point", and $v$ is the "principal part". Specifying $v$ alone is not enough. This is very similar to the relationship between points and vectors in an affine space (e.g. $\mathbb R^n$ considered as a set of points). Here, a vector is the difference of two points, but a vector itself doesn't have a base point. Thus, the vector can be attached to any point.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also answer my two (more specific) questions concerning  3) ? That'd be great!!

Comment: @arila Regarding 3): One can define surfaces (and more generally hypersurfaces) without a surrounding space $\mathbb R^n.$ Such things are called manifolds, and one also can define tangent vectors on them. One way of doing this is the construction with curves I mentioned in my answer. We don't need a scalar product for doing that. It is possible (and interesting) to define scalar products for these tangent vectors. This, then, is the realm of Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @arila [continued] The "trick" is basically the fact that, if we have a vector depending smoothly on a parameter $t$ (namely $c(t)$), and the Euclidean norm of this vector is constant, then this vector is orthogonal to its derivative with respect to $t.$ This and similar arguments are used often in classical differential geometry. A quick search with Google turned up [this document](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/DGnotes.pdf) which, at a superficial glance, seems to have it all. You may want to skim through that.